# User registration form validate and submit hooks not called

Tags: 7, forms

I try to add custom validation or submit function to the user registration form, but nothing works.

Here is the code in /sites/all/themes/mytheme/template.php:

```
function mytheme_user_register_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}
function mytheme_form_user_register_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}
function mytheme_user_register_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}
function mytheme_user_register_form_submit (&$form, &$form_state) {}
function mytheme_profile_user_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}
```

I also put similar code to /sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule/mymodule.module:

```
function mymodule_user_register_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}
function mymodule_user_register_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}
function mymodule_user_register_form_submit (&$form, &$form_state) {}
function mymodule_profile_user_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {}
```

None of the above functions are called and I have ran out of ideas.
As a proof that something works on this form, here is something that does work:

```
function mytheme_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {}
```

This gets called!! But I need to validate...

By the way, the debugger shows (among other) this when debugging the hook_form_alter:

```
$form['#validate'][0] = 'user_account_form_validate'
$form['#validate'][1] = 'user_validate_picture'
$form['#validate'][2] = 'user_register_validate'
$form['#validate'][3] = 'profile_user_form_validate'
```

Comment: First, your form functions shouldn't go into your theme, so you'd better use module hooks.

For your hooks to be taken into account, you have to clear the classes cache. Did you ?

Comment: Yeah, I cleared all caches. It's a bit strange that validation must go to module and not theme, but anyway, module hooks don't work either.

Comment: It's not strange : theme is for presentation, module for business logic. You can use the simplest and more general hook for your form : hook_form_alter and then test for your form's name inside the hook. As for the custom function, petiar advice below is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this in your hook_form_alter:

`$form['#validate'][] = 'your_validation_function';`

This way you can define an additional validation functions. Make sure you report all validation errors using the `form_set_error()` function.

Comment: It is working! I was just wondering why the "normal" hooks don't get called. Nowhere in the documentation it is written that in order to use the hooks you have to add them manually to form validate array (and added function doesn't need to be strictly a hook, like in the example above)

Comment: It's the other way around : a validation function is just a standard function, not a hook. Hooks don't have to be added to be usable : you just have to use the correct namespace, which you probably didn't in your examples.

Comment: Considering all that was already said (use hook in a module and check form id for proper naming), my example contains one function that should be in the correct namespace: mymodule_user_register_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) because the form id is "user_register_form". So at least this one should get called, according to [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/751826#validating)

Comment: @camcam Themes can just implement hooks called from `drupal_alter()`, which means those hooks whose name ends with "_alter()"; the other hooks cannot be implemented in themes.